# Computing lebesgue integral with triangular functions and logarithm

Tags: definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

For $-\pi/2 < s < \pi/2$, I am trying to compute
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}  \tan\theta\log\left|\frac{\sin (\theta + s)}{\sin (\theta - s)}\right| \,d\mu(\theta),
$$
where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

After numerical integration on several values of $s$, I believe result of the equation is $s$.

However, I'm confused on how to compute the equation. I have tried contour integration with complex variables, but I'm not sure how to take care of complex integrals w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. Can someone give hints or helps?